# XSD: XML validation to allow an empty string

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:element name="SpouseVisionPlanExist" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:union memberTypes="EmptyStrings Int"/>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="EmptyStrings">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Int">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[01]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

If i provide an empty value as

```
<SpouseVisionPlanExist></SpouseVisionPlanExist>
```

I get a validation error. It says, "The 'SpouseVisionPlanExist' element is invalid - The value '
    ' is invalid according to its datatype 'Union' - The value '
    ' is not valid according to any of the memberTypes of the union."

Comment: Try : `<xs:element name="SpouseVisionPlanExist" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>`

Comment: nillable is used to specify if the entire Tag  is optional.

Comment: if i give <SpouseVisiobPlanExist/> then it is working fine..but with both start and end tag.. it throw error

Comment: you have to implement union for empty string.,